# How to setup Tethering via USB?

Tags: wireless, 3g, tethering

[This Article](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/tips-tricks/how-to-tether-iphone-3g3gs-over-usbbluetooth-on-3-0-firmware/) (the "How to setup Tethering via USB on Windows" section) lists simple ways to share the 3G connection from  a tethered phone with other computers.

How could I do this with Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: This is with an iPhone, right?

Comment: Hi! It's: Computer with Modem USB 3G >>> share >>> Wifi for others computers. I haven't a mobile with Internet.

Comment: I don't understand your comment - what do you mean by "others computers"? And surely your tethered phone is "a mobile with internet"....  It works fine for me from an Android using the standard "USB tethering" feature in the USB connection type dialog (which was introduced in version 2.2 I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a computer running Ubuntu (connected to internet via 3G) and a working wifi card, the procedure to share the 3G internet with other computers is very easy.

After you connect to the internet, right click on the network manager icon on system tray and click on "Create Wireless Network." Follow the on screen instructions and connect the other computers via wifi from the network manager.

Comment: You explained how to do it through Wi-Fi when the question was about USB. So how to do it with USB?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to use USB thethering over wifi and over bluetooth? If not you need to make sure you get that first:

[image: im1]
<sub>random pix from the web</sub>

- To enable USB tethering you need to install ipheth-dkms and ipheth-utils.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ipheth-dkms ipheth-utils
```

Activate internet sharing with USB.

- To enable the use of tethering with Bluetooth

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Activate internet sharing via bluetooth, and use blueman to pair it as an access point.

<sub>untested</sub>

Comment: Hi! Thanks Rinzwind, but I want this:
Computer with Modem USB 3G >>> share >>> Wifi for others computers. I haven't a mobile with Internet.